# What does it mean of "on $E$ relative to $E$"

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In my textbook, Measure and Integral by Wheeden and Zygmund, often uses a phrase "on $E$ relative $E$".

---

Examples;

$f$ is uniformly continuous ***on*** $E$ relative to $E$.

The functions are continuous ***in*** $E$ relative to $E$.

---

I felt really weird because of repetitive mentions of $E$.

I don't know why they said "relative to $E$" although they already mentioned "on $E$" or "in $E$".

Moreover, is there any differences between "on $E$" and "in $E$"?